# Is this reduce function using spread or rest?

Tags: javascript, rest, reduce, spread

I am having a little trouble differentiating between spread and rest. Could someone explain to me if either spread or rest is being used within the reduce functions return statement?

This is what I am not understanding:

```
return [currentValue, ...accumulator]
```

inside of

```
let str = 'KING';

const reverseStr = str => {
  return str
    .split('')
    .reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
      return [currentValue, ...accumulator];
    }, [])
    .join('');
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest syntax always creates (or assigns to) a variable, eg:

```
const [itemOne, ...rest] = arr;
//     ^^ created  ^^^^
```

Spread syntax only results in another array (or object) *expression* - it doesn't put anything into variables. Here, you're using spread syntax to create a new array composed of `currentValue` and the values of `accumulator`.

```
return [currentValue, ...accumulator];
```

is like

```
return [currentValue, accumulator[0], accumulator[1], accumulator[2] /* ... */];
```

You're *spreading* the items of `accumulator` into the array that's being returned.

Comment: You have cleared the fog around this for me. Many thanks!